# Sorting 3 columns ( 2 numerical data and 1 text) with duplicate values in descending order using excel formula only

Tags: sorting, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have explored different solutions suggestions on stackoverflow. Honestly, got a lot of `#NUM!` , `#VALUE!` Looks like I really need help on this.

Sharing my effort so far.

```
A           B          C
Doc         Ref        A-Ref
3904        1234       3904
3904        1237       3904-1
3904        1235       3904-2
3907        1110       3907
3907        1111       3907-1
```

This is the sample data that I'm working on. I'd want to sort 3 columns  by descending order (2 numeric cols, Col C is not numeric because of hyphen) by only using excel formula - no VBA or SORT ribbon)

- Column D = Rank of Numeric Col A - formula used is `=RANK(A2,A$2:A$6)`
- Column E = Rank of Numeric Col B - formula used is `=RANK(B2,B$2:B$E)`

On Column C - since it has hyphen, - I may not be able to use RANK
Therefore not sure what will work here - [pthere was a resource about sorting text first 3 letters by desc on stackoverflow, but mine has "spl character hyphen with numbers and so it's text" - that solution won't help me]

Now after RANK, What next?
How can I ensure that Col A is ordered by descending and it's respective Col B entries is turn ordered by descending and therefore Col C.

There will be duplicates on Col A, and at the max Col B. 
Col C will be unique (therefore we'll not have to create any intermediate column) but Col C can be blank as well

Please please help!

Comment: Can you use a 'helper' column or does it all have to be done in one formula?

Comment: Yes, as many columns. No limit.

Answer (score 0):

For non-numerical ranking, you may use `COUNTIF`.

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$6,"<="&B2)
```

Hope this helps..